# Python and/or statements?

Tags: python-3.x

First year Comp Sci student here :P

I'm confused as to why this code isn't working like I expected it to (the while loop is just there for me to easily check cases):

```
i = 0

while i == 0:
    cpscCourseTaken = input("What Computer course have you taken: ")
    mathCourseTaken = input("What Math course have you taken: ")


    if cpscCourseTaken == ("CPSC 219" or "CPSC 233" or "CPSC 235")\
       and mathCourseTaken == ("MATH 271" or "MATH 273"):
        print("Prerequisites met\n")
    else:
        print("Prerequisites not met\n")
```

It is only printing "Prerequisites met" if you put in "CPSC 219" for the first input and "MATH 271" for the second.

Comment: You could have seen for yourself if you would have tried to reduce and reduce the example until the strange behavior vanished. In the end you would have printed "CPSC 233" or "CPSC 235" and see what's going on. This strategy helps a lot.

Answer (score 5):

One way to solve this is to use `in`:

```
if cpscCourseTaken in ("CPSC 219", "CPSC 233", "CPSC 235")\
   and mathCourseTaken in ("MATH 271", "MATH 273"):
```

Your code as posted first evaluates `"CPSC 219" or "CPSC 233" or "CPSC 235"`, which according to the rules of Python ends up being just `"CPSC 235"`, and then compares that single value to `cpscCourseTaken`.

The `in` operator checks whether the item on the left hand side is contained in the collection on the right hand side (in this case, the `( )` indicates the right hand side is a tuple).

Answer (score 0):

To give you a little more flexibility, try regexes:

```
if (re.match('CPSC (219|233|235)', cpscCourseTaken) and\ 
   re.match('MATH (271|273)', mathCourseTaken)):
```

or some fuzziness to allow whitespace

```
if (re.search('CPSC\s+(219|233|235)', cpscCourseTaken) and\ 
   re.search('MATH\s+(271|273)', mathCourseTaken)):
```

Comment: If you do use regexes, it's worthwhile to anchor the start and end so it doesn't unintentionally match things like `SMATH 2712`.